# FaultMessage: Version v8 is deprecated. Requests to this version will be blocked. - Google ADS API

Tags: python, google-ads-api

I'm trying to get campaign information with Google ADS API. The sample code snippet I used is from the official googleads [github repo](https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-python/blob/main/examples/campaign_management/get_campaigns_by_label.py).

```
import argparse
import sys

from google.ads.googleads.client import GoogleAdsClient
from google.ads.googleads.errors import GoogleAdsException

_DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE = 1000

# [START get_campaigns_by_label]
def main(client, customer_id, label_id, page_size):
    """Demonstrates how to retrieve all campaigns by a given label ID.

    Args:
        client: An initialized GoogleAdsClient instance.
        customer_id: A client customer ID str.
        label_id: A label ID to use when searching for campaigns.
        page_size: An int of the number of results to include in each page of
            results.
    """
    ga_service = client.get_service("GoogleAdsService")

    # Creates a query that will retrieve all campaign labels with the
    # specified label ID.
    query = f"""
        SELECT
            campaign.id,
            campaign.name,
            label.id,
            label.name
         FROM campaign_label
         WHERE label.id = "{label_id}"
         ORDER BY campaign.id"""

    # Retrieves a google.api_core.page_iterator.GRPCIterator instance
    # initialized with the specified request parameters.
    request = client.get_type("SearchGoogleAdsRequest")
    request.customer_id = customer_id
    request.query = query
    request.page_size = page_size

    iterator = ga_service.search(request=request)

    # Iterates over all rows in all pages and prints the requested field
    # values for the campaigns and labels in each row. The results include
    # the campaign and label objects because these were included in the
    # search criteria.
    for row in iterator:
        print(
            f'Campaign found with ID "{row.campaign.id}", name '
            f'"{row.campaign.name}", and label "{row.label.name}".'
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # GoogleAdsClient will read the google-ads.yaml configuration file in the
    # home directory if none is specified.
    googleads_client = GoogleAdsClient.load_from_storage(version="v10")

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description="Lists all campaigns for specified customer."
    )
    # The following argument(s) should be provided to run the example.
    parser.add_argument(
        "-c",
        "--customer_id",
        type=str,
        required=True,
        help="The Google Ads customer ID.",
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "-l",
        "--label_id",
        type=str,
        required=True,
        help="A label ID associated with a campaign.",
    )
    args = parser.parse_args()

    try:
        main(
            googleads_client,
            args.customer_id,
            args.label_id,
            _DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE,
        )
    except GoogleAdsException as ex:
        print(
            f'Request with ID "{ex.request_id}" failed with status '
            f'"{ex.error.code().name}" and includes the following errors:'
        )
        for error in ex.failure.errors:
            print(f'\tError with message "{error.message}".')
            if error.location:
                for field_path_element in error.location.field_path_elements:
                    print(f"\t\tOn field: {field_path_element.field_name}")
        sys.exit(1)
```

When I run the above .py file, I get the following error.

```
ValueError: Specified Google Ads API version "v10" does not exist. Valid API versions are: "v8", "v7", "v6"
```

But when I change the version on *"GoogleAdsClient.load_from_storage(version="v10")"*
to v8, this time I get the following error.

```
Request made: ClientCustomerId: XXXXXXX, Host: googleads.googleapis.com, Method: /google.ads.googleads.v8.services.GoogleAdsService/Search, RequestId: XXXXXXXXX,IsFault: True, FaultMessage:  Version v8 is deprecated. Requests to this version will be blocked.
```

By the way, I'm sure the google-ads package is up to date. Previously, I ran the following.

```
pip uninstall google-ads
pip install google-ads
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It still does look like you have an old version of `google-ads` installed. Can you start a Python interpreter and do:

```python
>>> import google.ads.googleads
>>> print(google.ads.googleads.VERSION)
```

Latest version would print `'17.0.0'`. You'll need at least version 15 in order to be able to use `v10` of the API. From the supported API version list in the error you provided, it seems you have something between version 12 and 14 of the library installed.